# Missing files when running a Talend perl job from the command line

Tags: linux, perl, talend

I created a simple talend perl job to extract data from an excel file and place it in a mysql table.
This works fine when I run it in talend studio 4.1.1.

The problem is when I export the job. I try to run it like so:

> perl -Ilib
>   proj.job_import_prods_0.1.pl
>   --context=Default --context_param file_path="/home/antoniocs/programming/file.xls"
>   $*

This gives me the following errors:

> Can't locate IO/Scalar.pm in @INC
>   (@INC contains:
>   /home/antoniocs/programming/ lib
>   /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1
>   /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1
>   /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5
>   /usr/lib/perl/5.10
>   /usr/share/perl/5.10
>   /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at
>   lib/OLE/Storage_Lite.pm line 171.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   lib/OLE/Storage_Lite.pm line 171.
>   Compilation failed in require at
>   lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm line 18.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm line 18.
>   Compilation failed in require at
>   proj.job_import_prods_0.1.pl line 568.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   proj.job_import_prods_0.1.pl line 568.

I have already placed the ParseExcel.pm int the lib folder in the folder of the job. Is there no way talend will automatically add the necessary files to the job's folder?

NOTE: When exporting the job I checked the box "export dependencies"
EXTRA NOTE: I am not a perl programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the path where `talend` stores Perl modules (you cant just move files around).  Once you know that, you can create a `PERL5LIB` environment variable to tell `perl` where the modules it is looking for are stored:

```
PERL5LIB=/path/to/modules perl -Ilib proj.job_import_prods_0.1.pl --context=Default --context_param file_path="/home/antoniocs/programming/file.xls" $*
```

A quick `find /where/talend/lives -name Scalar.pm` should give you a clue (you want the directory before `IO`).  If you wind up needing multiple directories, they can be separated with a `:` just like in the `PATH` environment variable.

Alternatively, you can install the required modules from your package manager (hint, RedHat style boxes use names like perl-IO-Scalar and Debian style boxes use names like libio-scalar-perl) or [CPAN](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=install+cpan+modules).

Comment: Module `IO::Scalar` lives in the distribution [IO-stringy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO-stringy/), so the RPM name is [perl-IO-stringy](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=perl-IO-stringy) and the deb name is [libio-stringy-perl](http://packages.debian.org/de/sid/libio-stringy-perl).

Comment: Thanks! The files were all in talend dir. I just copied them to the job lib folder and it all worked out great :) Thanks again (I also posted this in the talend forum and nobody responded. GO STACKOVERFLOW)